# How to Handle a Coinbase Callback in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, bitcoin, coinbase-api

How to Handle a Coinbase Callback in NodeJS to Recieve Instant Bit Coin Payment Notifications ?

Please I need example.

Note : I'm using SailsJS MVC Framework.

Comment: Show me the money! (code)

Comment: I found the PHP code. can you help me to convert it to NodeJS
http://www.phpthis.com/blog/?p=177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on your comment, I will give it a go.

I am assuming you have (or will have) an ExpressJs app.

**UPDATE** Sorry, I just noticed you're using sailsjs. The below should still be valid but you'll need to adapt it to work with the sails routing engine.

In your app, you need to define the post route:

```
// the app variable is the express js server

// name the route better than this...
app.post('/coinbase', function(req, res){

    var data = req.body;

    var orderId = data.order.id; 

    // etc...      

});
```

Comment: Do i need to send res.send(200); before handle data ?

Comment: You will need to do something like that, yeah. `res.end()` will also work but if you want to return json in the response make a call to `res.json({some: 'data'});`